# Finding out if $1/(1+x^2+y^2)$ integrable on $\Bbb R^2 $

Tags: calculus

I have a function $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2} $ and I want to know if it is integrable on $\Bbb R^2 $. How can I find out and prove it? My guess is it's integrable... but how can I integrate it, shall I use polar coordinates so that $x^2+y^2$ = $r^2$?

Answer (score 4):

Integrating along "shells"

$$ \int_{x^2+y^2\leq R^2}\frac{dx\,dy}{1+x^2+y^2} = \int_{0}^{R}\frac{2\pi \rho\,d\rho}{1+\rho^2} = \pi\log(1+R^2)$$
hence the given function does not belong to $L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Answer (score 3):

Pass to polar coordinates:

$$\iint_{\Bbb R^2}\frac{dxdy}{1+x^2+y^2}=\int_0^\infty\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{r\,d\theta\,dr}{1+r^2}=\left.\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{2r\,dr}{1+r^2}=\pi\log(1+r^2)\right|_0^\infty=$$

$$=\lim_{r\to\infty}\pi\log(1+r^2)$$

and since the last limit doesn't exist finitely the function's not integrable on the whole plane.